# PHP sprintf into HTML

Tags: php, html, web-applications

I have static HTML file which contains:

```
...
<td align="right"><a href="%s" target="_blank"><h5 style="color:#71ACD4!important">Activate</h5></a></td> 
...
```

and PHP script:

```
<?php
   $a = "http://www.example.com/activate?id=1213242";
   $html = file_get_contents('content.html');

   //I want to insert my $a into $html, 
   $new_html = sprintf($html, $a);
?>
```

`sprintf($html, $a)` does not work properly, because HTML file can contain '%' characters because of CSS styling. How can I manage above task?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Escape it with another %. In your style add one more % to the style to make sprintf work properly.

For Ex:

```
<table width="100%%" border="1">
<tr>
<td align="right" width="100%%" style="width:100%%;"><a href="%s" target="_blank"><h5 style="color:#71ACD4!important">Activate</h5></a></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.